# Google Map Find address

Tags: c#, google-maps

My scenario:

i'm using `Artem.GoogleMap.dll`

```
GoogleMarker oMarker = new GoogleMarker(42.1229, 24.7879);            
GoogleMap1.Markers.Add(oMarker);
```

i need to find the location[Address] for particular Latitude and Longitude how can i do this by using googlemap? don't wants to display in gmap insteed of that get the name of locaiton

sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation, it looks pretty easy:

http://googlemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Google%20Geocoder&referringTitle=Documentation

You need to create a GeoRequest object and pass in the lat/lng in the constructor, here is the sample code from the documentation:

```
   GeoRequest request = new GeoRequest(42.1438409, 24.7495615);
    GeoResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    string address = response.Results[0].FormattedAddress;
    // TODO use address values
```

Comment: i got the error 
Culture 'en' is a neutral culture. It cannot be used in formatting and parsing and therefore cannot be set as the thread's current culture.

Comment: Can you update your question with more details about what you have changed, where are you getting the error? You haven't provided enough information.

Comment: I am getting the following exception while executing this line                                                          GeoResponse response = request.GetResponse(); 
 "Culture 'en' is a neutral culture. It cannot be used in formatting and parsing and therefore cannot be set as the thread's current culture"